# YUI File upload component shortcut listed

Tags: yui, yui-uploader

We have a YUI upload component used in a Struts1.2 web application. This component has been configured with setFileFilters as to allow only TXT extension files. But when i open a folder with many text files and 1 shortcut, it listed this shortcut file (to another file in a different location) also.

and it allowed me to select all files in that folder (including the shortcut files). But then when clicking on 'Upload', i got an error saying "You cannot choose files from different directories".

I am not sure why YUI is listing the windows shortcut (.lnk) file even when the setFileFilters are set to "TXT". Has anyone faced this situation ?

Comment: YUI/JavaScript cannot influence the file browser prompt.

Comment: @jonas-g-drange thank you for the confirmation..  i was wondering why would it list the .lnk shortcut file since we have mentioned the 'File Filters' as TXT only.